# NSApplication Delegate Question

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsapplication

I was wondering if `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification` is still called when the system shuts down and the application is told to quit.

I'm working on an agent that needs to perform some actions when quitting, but I'm not sure if the delegate is called or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `applicationWillTerminate:` will be called. The best-practices for clean application shutdown are [documented by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AppArchitecture/Tasks/GracefulAppTermination.html).

Comment: Thank you - glad it calls the delegate!